# Poco WebSocket send flags

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

In the [WebSocket example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/WebSocketServer/src/WebSocketServer.cpp) is the code:

```
int flags;
n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
ws.sendFrame(buffer, n, flags);
```

The `flags` are an out-parameter in the `receiveFrame` and an in-parameter for `sendFrame`.

What is the significance of `flags` here and is it important that the send echoes the receive?

In my situation the server may send several frames without the client sending anything.  Should I make all of the sends use the same `flags` value as the most recent `receiveFrame` received, or what?

Answer (score 0):

The send echoes the receive in the example because all the example does is echoing. It is not mandated that flags are identical in send/receive. `Flag` is perhaps a misleading term because flags actually consist of flags and frame opcodes, see the [definitions](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/WebSocket.h#L62-L91).

Comment: I'm not sure when to use CONT, TEXT, BINARY or SETRAW. My packets contain human-readable text but I understand there are two different sorts of websocket (binary and non-binary)

Comment: [default](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/WebSocket.h#L194) will probably do fine